# How to change VSCode quick fix generated imports for TypeScript to use relative paths?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I use VSCode (1.17.2 at time of writing) with TypeScript (2.5.2). When I start to use a class in .ts file that is not yet imported, there is error and the class name i underlined with possibility to use Quick Fix bulp to import it. But it uses absolute path (actually relative to project root) to the file, e.g.

```
import { FormattedValue } from 'src/app/entities/formattedValue';
```

It works but when I create modules that can be just copied to different projects (having different project's folder structure) I need the paths to be relative. So when I start using e.g. `FormattedValue` in file `src/app/entities/xy.ts`, the generated import should look like

```
import { IFormattedValue } from './formattedValue';
```

Is there a way how to setup VSCode to use relative paths in quick fix generted imports?

Comment: See if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47330773/1028230 Looks like at 2.5.2 maybe not, but at 2.9+, you can with the `typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier` setting.

Answer (score 9):

In your vscode settings, add the following setting:

```
"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative"
```