# Is it possible to configure vs code such way that import will use absolute path (not relative)?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

VSCode after the last update now knows how to automatically add imports. However it adds using relative paths - any idea if that is somehow configurable?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is configurable if you are using VS Code 1.24 and TypeScript >= 2.9.

From the [release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_preferences-for-auto-imports-and-generated-code),

> #### Preferences for auto imports and generated code
>
> You can now explicitly specify the quote and path styles that VS Code
>   uses for auto imports and other generated JavaScript and TypeScript
>   code.
>
> [...]
>
> The `javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier` and
>   `typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier` settings specify the type
>   of path to use for imports.
>
> Valid values are:
>
> - `"relative"` to the file location.
> - `"non-relative"` based on the `baseUrl` configured in your `jsconfig.json` / `tsconfig.json`.
> - `"auto"` to infer the shortest path type.
>
> These new preferences require TypeScript 2.9+.

Comment: Thanks!  Was a life-saver.  I am using tsconfig-paths and I like all the paths to be absolute.  This really helped!

Comment: In my case, working with NxMonoRepo v16+ including paths in tsconfig files, the usual solutions didn't always cut it. I had to install two VSCode extensions to resolve the issue: `steoates.autoimport` and `q.typescript-mono-repo-import-helper`.