# How to automatically rewrite relative import paths to absolute?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to rewrite all existing relative paths in my javascript/typescript project to absolute paths.

Example:

```
import example from "../../example"
```

would be rewritten to

```
import example from "src/components/example"
```

So I am looking for a script or similar to transform all these imports. Preferably it would be possible to run this as an npm script on precommit or similar.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Loosely related: for VS Code users, you might want to change the value of `typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier` (see [Is it possible to configure vs code such way that import will use absolute path (not relative)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47330773/11107541)).

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem and created an ESLint plugin to solve it. You can find it here: https://github.com/qDanik/eslint-plugin-path

Answer (score 0):

It looks like imports are done for static analysis and cannot truly be dynamic ([Importing modules using ES6 syntax and dynamic path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340005/importing-modules-using-es6-syntax-and-dynamic-path)).  I am wondering though if you can do something in the tsconfig.json to accomplish this.  Under the "compilerOptions: { ..., "paths": { "@components/*": "src/components/*".  I am not sure this will solve your use case but it may be worth a try. So your import would look like:

import { example } from "@components/example"

Comment: To be clear, the imports work as it is. I just need to rewrite all imports in the existing codebase automatically.

Comment: I think the example I provided will rewrite your import statements to map the paths of the imports to the key / value pair, so the compiler will transform anywhere the import has @components in the path to src/components.  I can see the problem being if you have directories within the components directory.