# How can I make VS Code not insert padding spaces inside JavaScript import curly braces?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code auto-completes JavaScript `import {A...}` as following:

```js
import { Action } from './action.js';
```

I would like to change it to:
*(remove spaces in the braces for `import` only)*

```js
import {Action} from './action.js';
```

Where can that be edited?

Comment: . @erosman does it *autocomplets* to that or *formats* to that? Do you use formatter and which one?\

Comment: @Dimava Yes... After entering `import {`, it adds the closing braces and then after entering A it provides a selection, and after choosing Action, it changes `{Action}` to `{ Action }` and automatically adds `from './action.js';`

Comment: related issue ticket: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15034

Answer (score 0):

it's easy first of all open `VS-Code` then in the `settings` from the menu, search for `javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces` in the search bar and uncheck the box to disable it!
then save it and restart `VS-Code` for the changes to take effect.

**Update**
open settings, then in the search bar, type `editor.formatOnType` and and check the box next to it.

Now, click on "Edit in settings.json" and add these lines:

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.insertSpaces": false
},
```

as you can see `editor.insertSpaces` setting is set to `false`, which will prevent spaces from being inserted between the braces and the import statement!
at the end save the changes and close it.

good luck !

Comment: Thank you but that is not the answer. I don't want to change the braces globally. I only want to change the `import` auto-complete.

Comment: `javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier` refers to the path and nothing to do with the format of the braces. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51074467/3529456

Comment: @erosman for last try, plz check again. and remember, you can modify the user settings for the JavaScript language.

Comment: I tested `insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces` and after unchecking, and even restarting, it didn't make any difference for the `import` in my example.